# qtip tooltip for Bigcommerce Stencil

Tags: jquery, tooltip, bigcommerce, qtip, jquery-ui-tooltip

I am trying to create this tooltip in my bigcommerce cornerstone theme.

I have followed all the steps. But the image itself does not appear on my site.

It is displayed in my content

```
<span id="service-time" style="display: none;">[INFO TO BE SHOWN WITH THE TOOLTIP]</span>
```

I use

```
`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>`

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/content/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.js"></script>`
```

This is the tooltips.js

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

  $("div[data-product-option-change] .form-field").each(function() {

 var optionLabel = $(this).sibling('.form-label small');

    var optionLabelText = optionLabel.children("label.form-label.form-label--alternate.form-label--inlineSmall").children(".form-label").text();
    // check that optionLabelText is not an empty string
    if ($("img", this).length < 1 && slugify(optionLabelText).trim().length) {
      $(this).sibling('.form-label small')
        .children("label.form-label.form-label--alternate.form-label--inlineSmall")
        .children(".form-label")
        .append("&nbsp;<div class='help_div' style='display: inline;'><img src='/content/help.gif'  alt='" + optionLabelText + "'/></div>");
    }
}
  });

  $('.help_div').each(function() {

    var slug = slugify($("img", this).prop('alt'));
    var html = $("#" + slug).html();
    var titleq = $("img", this).prop('alt').replace(/[^-a-zA-Z0-9,&\s]+/ig, '');
    titleq = "<strong style='font-size: 12px'>" + titleq + "</strong><br/>"
    if (!html) html = "Description not available yet."

    $(this).qtip({
      content: titleq + html,
      position: {
        corner: {
          tooltip: 'topRight',
          target: 'bottomLeft'
        }
      },
      style: {
        tip: {
          corner: 'rightTop',
          color: '#6699CC',
          size: {
            x: 15,
            y: 9
          }
        },
        background: '#6699CC',
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        border: {
          color: '#6699CC',
        }
      }
    });

  });

  function slugify(text) {
    text = text.replace(/[^-a-zA-Z0-9,&\s]+/ig, '');
    text = text.replace(/-/gi, "_");
    text = text.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
    text = text.replace(/\s/gi, "-");
    text = text.toLowerCase();
    return text;
  }

});
</script>
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div data-product-option-change="" style="">
<div class="form-field" data-product-attribute="set-select">
    <label class="form-label form-label--alternate form-label--inlineSmall" for="attribute_250">
        Service Time:

            <small>Required</small><span class="toolTip" title=""></span>
    </label>


</div>



<div class="form-field" data-product-attribute="input-text">
    <label class="form-label form-label--alternate form-label--inlineSmall" for="attribute_252">
        Event Name:

            <small>Required</small><span class="toolTip" title=""></span>
    </label>


</div>
</div>

<span id="service-time" style="display: none;">[INFO TO BE SHOWN WITH THE TOOLTIP]</span>
```

why isn't it working?

Comment: On your store, is the class for the option value actually "productAttributeValue"? It looks like these instructions may have been written for our legacy Theme platform and the class names may be different.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I checked and it seems the class is actually productOptions-list-item. I tried changing the class name. But still it doesnt work. any ideas?

Comment: Any errors in the console?

Comment: No errors at all.. have been working around for days but to no avail. this is the link of the page Im trying to get it done: http://store-cvnscu0qdh.mybigcommerce.com/rostrum

Comment: @KarenWhite I have configured the HTML portion. What Am I doing wrong here? Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there are some syntax errors in your js, and some issues still with the class selectors. Try this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

$(".form-field").each(function() {

var optionLabel = $(this).children('.form-label');
var optionLabelText = optionLabel.text();


if($("img", this).length < 1) {
$(this).children('.form-label.form-label--alternate.form-label--inlineSmall').append("&nbsp;<div class='help_div' style='float:right;'><img src='/content/help.gif'  alt='"+optionLabelText+"'/></div>");
}

});


  $('.help_div').each(function() {

    var slug = slugify($("img", this).prop('alt'));
    console.log(slug);
    var html = $("#" + slug).html();
    var titleq = $("img", this).prop('alt').replace(/[^-a-zA-Z0-9,&\s]+/ig, '');
    titleq = "<strong style='font-size: 12px'>" + titleq + "</strong><br/>"
    if (!html) html = "Description not available yet."

    $(this).qtip({
      content: titleq + html,
      position: {
        corner: {
          tooltip: 'topRight',
          target: 'bottomLeft'
        }
      },
      style: {
        tip: {
          corner: 'rightTop',
          color: '#6699CC',
          size: {
            x: 15,
            y: 9
          }
        },
        background: '#6699CC',
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        border: {
          color: '#6699CC',
        }
      }
    });

  });

  function slugify(text) {
    text = text.replace(/[^-a-zA-Z0-9,&\s]+/ig, '');
    text = text.replace(/-/gi, "_");
    text = text.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "");
    text = text.replace(/\s/gi, "-");
    text = text.toLowerCase();
    return text;
  }

  });
```

I was able to get this working using the code above and the tutorial you mentioned, but a couple of notes that might help:

- The version of the qtip plugin you're using (1.0.0) is deprecated, and it's not compatible with jQuery 1.9x and above. I had to use jQuery 1.6x to avoid errors from $.browser. See: http://qtip2.com/guides
- Make sure you're referencing your scripts in this order:

  1. jQuery library
  2. qtip plugin
  3. tooltip.js

The console log statement will print the slug variable as it loops through each option, which is what you need to set as the span ID to specify the message for each option.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply! Really needed it. I managed to get the image of the "?" to display. But when I hover over it, the textmessage or pop-up do not appear...What am I missing?

Comment: You're getting a console error for `.qtip is not a function`. So the qtip jquery plugin file isn't being recognized. Where are you referencing your jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.js file?

Comment: I got this working now! But when I control it from the product description from the dashboard, it doesnt appear.. The content for the tooltip..

Comment: Try console logging the slug variable to troubleshoot. Whatever that prints out is what you need to enter as the span ID in your product description to set the tootip content. For example `<span id="event-date--------------required" style="display:none">Hello, this is my tooltip text!</span>`

Comment: Hi, I tried to troubleshoot. But there were no results produced. Have been trying much to find the span ID. Didnt work :(

Comment: It looks like you are just console logging the # symbol as a string? `<script>
    console.log("#");
    </script>` I added the console log statement to the script in my answer to illustrate. The final `<span>` s that you add to your description field should look like the example in my previous comment.

Comment: I tried to display tooltip only when I've specified the content. Thus, I added the following `if (!html) { $(this).remove();}`. It worked by only showing the images which have the tooltip specified. but the content did not appear.. What am i missing here?